# Flask Page not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am new to flask. I am making a simple web-based app. However, one of the url is not working. All the other pages are working fine

My python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from openpyxl import load_workbook

app = Flask(__name__)

# Report Main Page
@app.route('/report')
def report():
    return render_template('report.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It have some other pages. All are working fine. However /report is not working, It returns a 404 error

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Did you try moving the route order around?

Comment: and `/input` is *really* working?

Comment: Can you post the non-simplified version of your code? Because the flask part of the simplified version is fine.

Comment: Have you got the home.html in a **templates/** folder?

Comment: post the route code, all the thing we might need to re-build the error you are getting. by the code you have pasted, `/input` is the route should throw error's. so show us some more of the code.

Comment: @hansaplast yes /input is working

Comment: @djromero - Edited

Comment: How are you running this? `python your-script.py`? some web server with possibly a `.htaccess` file messing up with your routes? what happens if you comment all routes and openpyxl code except the report routes?

Comment: can you try to put `    return render_template('input.html', clist=clist, detail1=in_detail1, detail2=in_detail2, detail3=in_detail3)` under `def report():`? Just to double check that it is not the `render_template` not finding the template triggering the 404?